# Three.js subdivisions and texture

Tags: three.js

I am trying to load an object with OBJLoader and subdivide every geometry, so it would look smoother... but when I do so, texture is being ruined. How to avoid that?

```
            var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(4);

            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'obj/'+model+'.obj', function ( object ) {

                var reflection = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( [ 'additional/background.jpg', 'additional/background.jpg', 'additional/background_top.jpg', 'additional/background_down.jpg', 'additional/background.jpg', 'additional/background.jpg' ] );

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {


                        child.geometry.mergeVertices()
                        child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                        child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
                        child.material.map = texture;



                        if(reflex){
                            child.material.envMap = reflection;
                            child.material.reflectivity = reflex;
                        }

                        modifier.modify(child.geometry);

                    }

                } );
```

Comment: My guess is that you're using a UV map, and thus it would have to be subdivided accordingly. The new vertices created probably do not have any UVs.

Comment: Not sure what are you talking about... how do I fix that?

Comment: First thing would be to fix your question (at least screenshots, runnable code is obviously better) so that people actually have something to look at. Also note that `THREE.SubdivisionModifier` is part of the examples, not of the core ... and going by your brief snippet, you're not doing the same work that's being done in `examples/webgl_geometry_subdivision.html`.